# Pluralization bug in flag remaining count

Tags: bug, plurals, flag-dialog

When flags remaining is equal to one flag, the text incorrectly shows "You have 1 flags left today".

[image: flag dialog with "You have 1 flags left today"]

Instead, it should show "You have 1 flag left today". Alternatively, it could be rephrased to avoid the need for pluralization: "Flags remaining today: 1".

Can this dialog be updated to (correctly) pluralize "1 flags", please?